# $\mathbb{Z}_p=\varprojlim \mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$ is uncountable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory, formal-completions

> The ring of $p$-adic integers is given by $\mathbb{Z}_p=\varprojlim \mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$. From this description how can we conclude that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is uncountable ?

It follows from the description that each nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is of infinite order (as an element of component wise additive group $\mathbb{Z}_p$). But I cannot produce any contradiction assuming countability of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Help me.

Comment: I feel like there should be a topological argument around the corner. A compact and complete (ultra-)metric space being *countable*, but not finite … Seems somehow too stretched.

Comment: Every nonzero element of $\mathbb Z, \mathbb Q$ and many other countable groups has infinite order as well, so that has nothing to do with being uncountable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each element of $\Bbb Z_p$ has a "base-$p$" expansion
$$a_0+pa_1+p^2a_2+\cdots$$
with each $a_j\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1)$. Now use the Cantor diagonalisation argument.

Comment: The important fact here is rather that every such expansion corresponds to an element (every element of $\mathbb N$ has such an expansion, otherwise)

Comment: Agreed with @MaximeRenzi, and to be absolutely precise, we should also use that different expansions correspond to different elements i.e. we really have a *bijection* there.